# Inconsistent job scheduling by job scheduler

Tags: java, android, android-notifications, job-scheduling, android-jobscheduler

I used job scheduler for sending notification at whatever time interval lets say 4 minutes at regular interval so I used

> setPeriodic(duration * 60 * 1000);   //duration is 4 minutes

but its inconsistent first it sends notification after 1 minute or 2 minute then 1 minute then 4 minutes then 8 minutes also I guess it caches previous duration, its here how I implemented code:

```
    public static void Scheduler(Context context){

    ComponentName componentName = new 
              ComponentName(context, ClsJobService.class);

    JobInfo.Builder builder =  new JobInfo.Builder(0, componentName)

           .setPeriodic(duration * 60 * 1000);
    JobScheduler jobScheduler =  (JobScheduler) 
              context.getSystemService (Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
    jobScheduler.schedule(builder.build());

}
```

Comment: What Android version are you using?

Comment: Lollipop, sony Xperia z1s

Answer (score 1):

You have scheduled a job at the 4-minute interval using JobScheduler on Android L. Once scheduled as periodic, this job can run only once at any time within the interval you set (start: the time you called schedule(), end: plus 4 minutes). And it will only run again after finishing the interval that it has run, only in the new range.... this behavior will continue on until you cancel the job.

> **e.g:** the job was scheduled for 4 minutes as periodic, and 1 minute later it was executed; This job will be run again after 3 minutes, according to the 4 minutes range. In new range, it can execute at any time within 4 min.

If you don't want this periodic behavior from `JobScheduler`, consider use `AlarmManager` service to schedule your job to trigger a notification every 4min and reschedule it after triggering the notification.

**Obs.:** `JobScheduler` uses the `AlarmManager` service internally, to schedule a job that need be scheduled, defining the start and end times to run this job.

> **Android L source code references:**
>
> - [To set times for scheduling a periodic job](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-release/services/core/java/com/android/server/job/controllers/JobStatus.java#L85)
> - [To set times for rescheduled the periodic job](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-release/services/core/java/com/android/server/job/JobSchedulerService.java#L437)
> - [When the periodic job is scheduled using AlarmManager](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-release/services/core/java/com/android/server/job/controllers/TimeController.java#L91)

Answer (score 0):

This is working as designed. (and part of the "power" of the JobScheduler)

From the docs:

> `setPeriodic()`: Specify that this job should recur with the provided interval and
>   flex. **The job can execute at any time** in a window of flex length at
>   the end of the period.

Comment: So what could we do to fire notification at exact interval

Comment: AlarmManager is your best option. Take a look here: https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Comment: Suppose we need to schedule a task every 4 minutes do we need to set alarm every 4 minutes? What im doing is to have one alarm that starts scheduler and other alarm that cancels job scheduler, also see other answer beside you, who suggested tasktimer, what about it

Comment: AlarmManager allows you to schedule and to cancel pending alarms. It's more fitting for your needs then TaskTimer.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you user Timertask for the same?

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html

Comment: This wouldn't provide the right guarantees on Android. For example, `JobScheduler` starts your job even if your application isn't currently running.